# shell_exec not if does not work

Tags: php, if-statement, shell-exec

check.sh has got echo "error01"
hope you can help
this does not work

```
<?php
$c = shell_exec("check.sh 2>&1");
if($a == "error01"){exit("TEST");}
echo "Wellcome";
?>
```

But this does

```
<?php
$c = shell_exec("check.sh 2>&1");
if(isset($c)){exit("TEST");}
echo "Wellcome";
?>
```

Comment: The title is meant to be shell_exec if does not work

Comment: can you explain what your talking about in text please

Comment: isn't $a undefined in the first example?

Comment: When i use  $c = shell_exec("check.sh");

Comment: i can echo it but not use if

Comment: Yes its c$ sorry about that

Comment: debug: `var_dump($c);` could have a line break or something else there

Comment: Okay thanks for your help

Comment: it does not work my test was $w = "check.sh test";
$out = shell_exec("$w 2>&1");
var_dump($o);
if($o == "helloworld"){exit("Test");} Output from var_dump string(11) "helloworld " if still not working

Comment: on test $out is $o that was a typo on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding `$a = substr($out, 0, -1);` then the if statement `if($a == "string");`after it as the shellscript puts a space for some reason

**Thanks nogad for showing me about it returning 11 characters when it should be 10 characters**

Comment: seems like a terrible idea if your fix the source and the space is removed this will fail, at least  use trim

Comment: trim will remove all spaces and there is not a way for me to remove the space as the code in the shellscript is just if [ "$1" = "example" ]
then
echo "Example"
fi with no spaces

Comment: Nogad any good ways to get devs for not any money :/ as i do not get money out of the website its hard to give them money for there hard work : ( Domain is revfirmware.ml

Answer (score 0):

```
"helloworld " !="helloworld"
```

your returning 11 charters but checking for 10. Either edit the php or the shell script.

you could apply trim(), but it would be better to edit the file variable

Comment: there is if [ "$1" = "" ]
then
echo "helloworld"
fi no space

Comment: so if it found a way to remove the last space in php that would be the answer then thanks a lot